# How can you calculate formulas like this in ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

I can do it with pen & paper but I'm having a really hard time trying to build methods in ruby that calculates simple formulas like the one below.

[image: formula]

How can I build a method in ruby that returns CET?

(To make it easier consider (dj-d0)/365 equals j)

Comment: Just make Ruby variables to represent each variable in the equation and loop from 1 to N performing the equation each time

Comment: Not really possible, CET is unknown, so I doubt it can be solved linearly without isolating CET somehow.

Comment: You didn't mention that CET was unknown in your question.

Comment: I kind of did (by wanting CET as return value) :D

Answer (score 2):

This can be translated almost literally to Ruby if you know the structures to use:

```
sum = (1..n).inject(0) do |s, j|
  fc[j] / ((1 + cet) ** (d[j] - d[0]) / 365) - fc[0]
end
```

If you want to *solve* for something, that's another story. You might want to try Mathematica.

Comment: I did something similar, the problem is that cet is the return value, so it need to be isolated, but I can't do it linearly.

Comment: Ruby is very good at *evaluating* functions but terrible at *solving* them.

Comment: Hey, this is a total-cost-of-operation formula for credit operations. This cannot be solved (not even in mathematica) it can only be approximated. This is the solution, hope it helps: 
https://github.com/eduardordm/cet-ruby/blob/master/cet.rb